# WSO2 API Manager Analytics Accuracy

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

We've deployed WSO2 Api Manager in Active-Active scheme with single Api Manager Analytics server. Also we're using Graylog+Elastic+Grafana to collect logs from back-end services behind API.
The case is that amount of back-end services calls are hugely greater (millions vs thousands) than a corresponding API hits count. Why is that? What are we missing?

Comment: what's your APIM version?

Comment: similar issue has been fixed in 2.2.0 https://github.com/wso2/analytics-apim/issues/397

Comment: Thanks, @Bee, we're using 2.1.0 and going to update to 2.6.0. Glad to know that it had been fixed.